# java.lang.VerifyError while running Pig in Eclipse using Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop, apache-pig

Am trying to execute Apache Pig code from Eclipse as mentioned in http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/test.html

Below are the codes :

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.pigtutorial.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>chap01</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>chap01</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jline</groupId>
            <artifactId>jline</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
            <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
            <artifactId>pigunit</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

PigUnit Test Case :

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pig.pigunit.PigTest;
import org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.ParseException;
import org.junit.Test;


public class PigUnitTestPractise {
      @Test
      public void testTop2Queries() throws IOException, ParseException {
        String[] args = {
            "n=2",
            };

        PigTest test = new PigTest("resources/top_queries.pig", args);

        String[] input = {
            "yahoo",
            "yahoo",
            "yahoo",
            "twitter",
            "facebook",
            "facebook",
            "linkedin",
        };

        String[] output = {
            "(yahoo,3)",
            "(facebook,2)",
        };

        test.assertOutput("data", input, "queries_limit", output);
      }

}
```

Error :

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTrackerInstrumentation, method: create signature: (Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTrackerInstrumentation;) Incompatible argument to function
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner.<init>(LocalJobRunner.java:573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:479)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:158)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1322)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1307)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:978)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:942)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:855)
    at com.pigtutorial.examples.chap00.TestCurrentTime.testAllCurrentTimeSame(TestCurrentTime.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

As per the post [java.lang.VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105578/java-lang-verifyerror), I may have problem in order of import.

As per [How to fix java.lang.VerifyError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398295/how-to-fix-java-lang-verifyerror), I may be "running against a different version of a library than the code was compiled against".

How to find the exact source of the problem ? Which JAR is creating the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find the root cause, however solved the error using different dependencies. I used CDH4.5 repository jars in maven dependency to solve the problem.

Changed only pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.pigtutorial.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>chap01</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>chap01</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-cdh4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jline</groupId>
            <artifactId>jline</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
            <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.0-cdh4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
            <artifactId>pigunit</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.0-cdh4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

P.S
Does this seem to be incompatibility between the Pig and Hadoop API (i,e Pig 0.12 is not compatible to work on hadoop 2.2.0) ?